# custom domain email forwarding catchall recovery

Tags: email, smtp, forwarding

In short, I'm trying to restore mailflow for a free domain I setup with unonic. (3 technically)

They worked fine for about a year. *@example.tld would all forward to my@personal.email. January 6th, everything started bouncing and I haven't stopped drinking since then.

```
example@unonic.whatever: host mail.popdns.com[88.198.61.190] said: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [62.4.1.33] blocked using dnsbl.ahbl.org; List shut down. See: http://www.ahbl.org/content/last-notice-wildcarding-services-jan-1st[1] (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

Dozens of support tickets I opened have gone unanswered.
I've attempted to point the domain to namecheap but their system won't allow it.
I've attempted to reroute via mailgun but that isn't working either.

1) I'd like any and all suggestions to be able to receive emails to that domain again. I have a free VPS at my disposal if that could be useful.

2) I'm also interested (for a more permanent and reliable future setup) in what other free solutions to this type of need exist. Which other providers offer free email catchall forwarding (and other nifty things?) and/or what other specialized solutions such as mailgun exist? What do YOU use?

Comment: I'm fine with moving it/reposting it elsewhere but they said not on serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options that come to mind.  Take your available VPS and create your own email server.  Quite entailed but there are several how-tos on how to do this.  Just google "you flavor of linux " + mail server and you'll find them.

Personally, what I would do though, if I uderstand you correctly, is check out Zoho for email.  I used to default to google for things like this but they no longer offer free "business" accounts where you can modify your MX records of your domain to point to Google apps.  However, Zoho still offers free accounts up to 10 unique addresses.  Once you set up you domain's MX records to point at Zoho, you could then forward those accounts wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In an ideal situation, either would work. The problem is unonic throws an error mentioning a DNSBL no matter which third party DNS I tell it to use. Zoho mail or mailgun would work, but unonic won't allow the creation of one of the records they require for verification. I even tried the HTML method... Additionally, they are not responding to ANY contact. This is rediculous.

Comment: @bumblingfool  admittedly I did not know what unonic was when I responded nor did I scroll through the bounce message.  I've dealt with blacklist inclusions before and was able to simple submit the required forms to have my IP address removed.  Unfortunately, I don't think that would be an option for you so long as you are using unonic.  I would venture to say that a free service such as the one they provide is bound to be utilized by tons of spammers.  In short, my suggestion is to purchase real domains and either pay for hosting or host the domains yourself.